# When I run rails server it is showing error about database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have ROR version 4.0.0 and ruby version 2.0.0.After creating the project app when I try to run rails server it is showing me the error about yml file.
 The screen looks like this

```
    C:\Sites\app>rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/ap
plication/configuration.rb:113:in `rescue in database_configuration': YAML synta
x error occurred while parsing C:/Sites/app/config/database.yml. Please note tha
t YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error:
(<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 9 c
olumn 3 (RuntimeError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:103:in `database_configuration'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4
.0.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:174:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4
.0.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:173:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block i
n tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (
2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_st
rongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block i
n each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_st
rongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_e
ach'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
```

Please help me on it.

Comment: Show your database.yml you have indentation problems

Comment: Post your `database.yml`

Comment: Did you read what the error says especially the following "YAML synta x error occurred while parsing C:/Sites/app/config/database.yml. Please note tha t YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 9 c "

Comment: ok m displaying my database.yml

Comment: `development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: postgres
  username:postgres
  password:191192
  pool:5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: postgres
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database:postgres
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check your YAML file using some kind of [YAML Validator](http://yamllint.com/)

Here is your valid YAML:

```
development: 
  adapter: postgresql
  database: postgres
  password: 191192
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: postgres
production: 
  adapter: postgresql
  database: postgres
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
test: 
  adapter: postgresql
  database: postgres
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have tabs instead of spaces in your `database.yml`.

Quick fix in vim:

```
:%s/\t/  /g
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the trace, it tells you exactly what is wrong with your database.yml file.

```
"Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed."
```

and

```
"could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 9 column 3"
```

So make sure that you are using spaces, not tabs, and see if you are missing a colon in line 9.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add in:

```
host:localhost
```

turns out I should have added:

```
host: localhost
```

with one space after ":"

hope this helps